# Find out who evokes a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle PL/SQL procedure monitoring_5_min and as far as I know it must be envoked every 5 minutes by some external interface (possibly a web service) or some scheduled job. Are there any Oracle system methods to find out what invokes the procedure? Maybe some system views? I tried to select from v$sql but it seems that it only include SQL calls but not PL/SQL.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `dba_hist_active_sess_history`

Answer (score 1):

You can query v$session to get all the details:

```
select * from v$session where sid = sys_context('userenv','sid')
```

Also look at  `OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME`

Answer (score 0):

Alex, the most likely ways to run a task on a schedule in Oracle is either via cron (if on UNIX) or via DBMS_SCHEDULER.  You can look at both options, and query DBA_DEPENDENCIES for references to the stored procedure providing the the task is not actually using anonymous PL/SQL.

While the SP is being ran you can find the calling session via V$ACCESS then via V$SESSION get the Oracle username, OS username, machinne the request is from, and program being invoked which can help identify the source.

The suggested use of dba_hist_active_sess_history requires that your site is licensed for the extra-cost EM Diagnostic Pack license.

Answer (score 0):

The v$sql view will have entries for both sql and pl/sql probably you are not seeing it as its caching out. Try looking in the DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT  view.
Another sure way to capture its execution is to enable auditing on this procedure execution. Auditing is a two step operation in Oracle; first you will have to enable Extended auditing on DB level and then you can set the auditing policy to log an audit event on execution of your procedure.